# CollectionView binding problem on iOS (works fine on Android or Windows)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I've been running into this problem for several days.

I have a ContentView that contains a CollectionView :

```
    <CollectionView
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
        SelectionMode="None"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentView}}, Path=NumberList}">
    
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               [...]
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

The ItemsSource for this CollectionView is bound to a BindableProperty (the property is in the behind code of the ContenView) :

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty NumberListProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(NumberList), typeof(ObservableCollection<int?>), typeof(NumberPicker));

    public ObservableCollection<int?> NumberList
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<int?>)GetValue(NumberListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumberListProperty, value); }
    }
```

All this works fine on Android or Windows, but as soon as the view is displayed on iOS, I have a crash (and the debugging stops).

In the output window I have an exception that doesn't help me much:

```
An error occurred: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')'. Callstack: '   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.TemplatedCell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].FindValue(Object key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.TemplatedCell, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].TryGetValue(Object key, TemplatedCell& value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.ItemsViewController`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ReorderableItemsView, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].UpdateTemplatedCell(TemplatedCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.ItemsViewController`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ReorderableItemsView, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].CreateMeasurementCell(NSIndexPath indexPath)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.ItemsViewController`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ReorderableItemsView, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].GetPrototype()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.ItemsViewLayout.DetermineCellSize()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.ListViewLayout.ConstrainTo(CGSize size)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.ItemsViewLayout.SetInitialConstraints(CGSize size)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.ItemsViewController`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ReorderableItemsView, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].EnsureLayoutInitialized()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.ItemsViewController`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ReorderableItemsView, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ViewDidLoad()
   at UIKit.UIViewController.get_View()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.ItemsViewHandler`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ReorderableItemsView, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].CreatePlatformView()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ReorderableItemsView, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[UIKit.UIView, Microsoft.iOS, Version=16.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].OnCreatePlatformView()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.ItemsViewHandler`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ReorderableItemsView, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnCreatePlatformView()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.OnCreatePlatformElement()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.CreatePlatformElement()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ReorderableItemsView, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[UIKit.UIView, Microsoft.iOS, Version=16.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ReorderableItemsView, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[UIKit.UIView, Microsoft.iOS, Version=16.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler handler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.MapContent(IContentViewHandler handler, IContentView page)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IContentViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ScrollViewHandler.UpdateContentView(IScrollView scrollView, IScrollViewHandler handler, ICrossPlatformLayout crossPlatformLayout)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ScrollViewHandler.MapContent(IScrollViewHandler handler, IScrollView scrollView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IScrollView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IScrollViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IScrollView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[UIKit.UIScrollView, Microsoft.iOS, Version=16.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IScrollView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[UIKit.UIScrollView, Microsoft.iOS, Version=16.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler handler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.MapContent(IContentViewHandler handler, IContentView page)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IContentViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ViewExtensions.ToHandler(IView view, IMauiContext context)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellSectionRenderer.PushPage(Page page, Boolean animated, TaskCompletionSource`1 completionSource)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellSectionRenderer.OnPushRequested(NavigationRequestedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellSectionRenderer.OnNavigationRequested(Object sender, NavigationRequestedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.InvokeNavigationRequest(NavigationRequestedEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.OnPushAsync(Page page, Boolean animated)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.PushStackOfPages(List`1 pages, Nullable`1 animate)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.GoToAsync(ShellNavigationRequest request, ShellRouteParameters queryData, IServiceProvider services, Nullable`1 animate, Boolean isRelativePopping)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellNavigationManager.GoToAsync(ShellNavigationParameters shellNavigationParameters, ShellNavigationRequest navigationRequest)
```

**Some tests I did :**

If I change the type of list from ObservableCollection to List, it changes nothing.

If I simplify the ItemTemplate (with a simple label displaying "hello", for example), it changes nothing.

If I turn my CollectionView into a VerticalStackLayout, it works (but that's not what I want).

In short, I'm stuck. Thanks in advance for your insights.

**EDIT:**

Small precision, I develop in .net 8. I was using .net 7 until recently, but I had other problems on iOS (including the keyboard that overlap the text boxes).

Comment: Was that a VerticalStackLayout with BindableLayout?

Comment: @StephenQuan I'm not sure I understand the question; I specify in my message that I'm using a CollectionView (among the tests I've done, I tried replacing this CollectionView with a VerticalStackLayout + BindableLayout and I found that the binding worked, but I don't want to use this configuration, I want it to work with a CollectionView, as is the case with Android).

Comment: Yeah I was trying to clarify if you were still using a collection since when you stated VerticalStackLayout it was ambiguous whether or not the collection was still being used or if you did something else.

Comment: Is this working in Android release?

Comment: @H.A.H. Yes it works perfectly on an Android device, whether it's release or debug.

Comment: @JeremyA. you lack specified DataType in your DataTemplate, and it works? (In release, I know debug gets it resolved by other means)

Comment: @H.A.H. It works, yes. (I'm on .net 8, which fixes some things... but obviously breaks others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got round the problem by changing my BindableProperty from a list of **"int?"** to a list of **"int"** (and by refactoring the logic of my component).

The iOS CollectionView doesn't seem to be comfortable with this notion of a nullable type.

As I'm happy with the refactoring I've done, I'm not going to look any further.